# manually specifying mysql_real_escape_string charset so no db connection required - possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

while i understand why mysql_real_escape_string requires an active mysql connection to escape various strings, i were hoping on the following:

some sort of way to manually (er, terminology here, perhaps 'statically' would be the correct term) push the charset to mysql_real_escape_string so that no active db connection is required to run mysql_real_escape_string.

as some people may ask why we want to mysql_real_escape_string without an active connection, the reasoning is simple:

```
a) construct query (this is where the mysql_real_escape_string takes place)
b) create hash (md5, md4, sha1, crc32, choose your poison) from said query
c) check cache (memcached) for hash created in step b
d) query cached in memcached -> return cached results -> terminate script
c) query NOT cached in memcached -> connect to mysql -> cache result to memcached + return result
```

so as you can see with the above, because a hash of the query is created prior to checking the cache / connecting to the db if needed... mysql_real_escape_string takes place BEFORE a db connection is made.

the whole goal of this is so that if we are able to execute a 'whole page request' purely from cache hits, there is just no need to connect to mysqld. period.

what we have now is a large set of requests where the a db connection is made just so that mysql_real_escape_string can execute. this seams un necessary.

so, to summarize:

we need to a way to SAFELY escape mysql strings (POST and GET values, so it needs to be 100% safe) without making a db connection.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a different approach:

```
function search(array $params) {
    $cacheKey = md5(serialize($params));

    ... search cache ...

}
```

You don't need to run the hash on the *query*, you can just run it on the supplied parameters. The query would supposedly be the same every time.

Comment: Although we did not end up using this answer, it is (from what we can see) the only way to do this. Altering the logic of the code needing to execute mysql_real_escape_string to hash the query prior to mysql_real_escape_string is the only way to do avoid mysql_real_escape_string all together, and in turn a db connection. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

As from php.net documentation website.

Comment: please view http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

"A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used."